# POST authentication using REST API with response key and checksum

Tags: r, rest, authentication, http-post, checksum

I am trying to authenticate to an API using POST method. Here is the documentation I am referring to [Kite Connect API](https://kite.trade/docs/connect/v1/?python#authentication).
I am unable to understand where I am going wrong. Mistake is with checksum or POST ?

```
library(digest)
require("httr")

my_api <- "xxx"
my_req_token <- 'yyy'
my_secret <- 'zzz'

check<-hmac(my_req_token,paste0(paste0(my_api,my_req_token),my_secret),algo=c('sha256'))

url <- 'https://api.kite.trade/session/token'
login <- list(api_key=my_api,
              request_token = my_req_token,
              checksum = check)

response<- POST(url,body= login)
```

This is the response I am receiving.

```
> response
Response [https://api.kite.trade/session/token]
Date: 2017-08-27 12:34
Status: 400
Content-Type: application/json
Size: 81 B

> content(response, "parsed", "application/json")
$status
[1] "error"

$message
[1] "Missing api_key"

$error_type
[1] "InputException"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue is resolved. post data should be sent as 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded', setting encode arg to form does this

```
library(digest)
require("httr")

my_api <- "xxx"
my_req_token <- 'yyy'
my_secret <- 'zzz'

#use digest insted of hmac; digest serializes argument first, use serialize arg to disable that
check<-digest(paste0(my_api, my_req_token, my_secret), algo='sha256', serialize=FALSE)

url <- 'https://api.kite.trade/session/token'
login <- list(api_key=my_api,
              request_token = my_req_token,
              checksum = check)

#post data should be sent as 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded', setting encode arg to form does this
response<- POST(url,body= login, encode='form')

parsed_content <- content(response, "parsed", "application/json")
```

Answer (score 0):

Give this a shot

```
#devtools::install_github("hrbrmstr/curlconverter")

library(curlconverter)

curlExample <- 'curl https://api.kite.trade/session/token
   -d "api_key=xxx"
   -d "request_token=yyy"
   -d "checksum=zzz"'

resp <- make_req(straighten(curlExample))
resp
```

Comment: `> resp
[[1]]
function () 
httr::VERB(verb = "GET", url = "https://api.kite.trade/session/token")
<environment: 0x0000000011ed3618>`

Comment: This is the response I got from the code. *added hmac for checksum